# Call custom customer attribute in block

Tags: magento2, blocks, customer-attribute

I have found a custom block that checks if the customer is logged in and edited it to this.  What I need it to do is check the custom customer attribute is_allowed is set to yes, too.  I want to use this in a block and call in it in phtml file.  Can you point me where I am going wrong?

the code is

```php
<?php

namespace WorldSynergy\LoginPortal\Block;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Url;
use Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Customer\Collection;
{

class Portal extends Template
{
    protected $_customerUrl;
    protected $_customer;
    protected $httpContext;
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context  $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Customer\Collection $customer,
        Url $customerUrl,
        Context $httpContext,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_customer->$customer;
        $this->_customerUrl = $customerUrl;
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function isLoggedIn()
    {
        if  $this->$_customer->create()->addAttributeToSelect('is_allowed') {
            return $this->httpContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
        }
    }
}
```

I can't seem figure it out.  Help is appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Replace `isLoggedIn()` Funtion With This And Try**

```
public function isLoggedIn()
    {
        if  ($this->$_customer->create()->addAttributeToSelect('is_allowed',array('eq'=>1))) {
            return $this->httpContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks!  I think this solved it

Comment: most welcome happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You have typo I guess, **$customer** remove **$** symbol.

```
<?php

namespace WorldSynergy\LoginPortal\Block;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Url;
use Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Customer\Collection;
{

class Portal extends Template
{
    protected $_customerUrl;
    protected $_customer;
    protected $httpContext;
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context  $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Customer\Collection $customer,
        Url $customerUrl,
        Context $httpContext,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_customer->$customer;
        $this->_customerUrl = $customerUrl;
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function isLoggedIn()
    {
        if $this->_customer->create()->addAttributeToSelect('is_allowed',array('eq'=>1))) {
            return $this->httpContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks!  the typo was $this->_customer->$customer; should be $this->_customer = $customer;

Comment: yeah i have mentioned in answer..